# How to return string array to java JNI

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, native

I want to return finalResult array to java. Any help Appreciated.

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_testjniproject_MainActivity_AnalyseImageDisplay(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jlong sourceImageArray)
{
    Mat &srcInputImg = *(Mat*)sourceImageArray;
    vector<tuple<string, string, int>> result = AnalyseImage(srcInputImg);
    enter code here
    string finalResult[3];
    for (int i=0; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << get<0>(result[i]) << " : " << get<1>(result[i]) << " With confidence " << get<2>(result[i]) << "%" << endl;
        finalResult[i] = get<1>(result[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this :

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_testjniproject_MainActivity_AnalyseImageDisplay(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject instance,
        jlong sourceImageArray) {
    jobjectArray result;
    result = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(3,env->FindClass("java/lang/String"),env->NewStringUTF(""));
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
         env->SetObjectArrayElement(result,i,env->NewStringUTF(finalResult[i].c_str()));
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: You could pass `nullptr` or `NULL` as initial value of the `NewObjectArray` call instead of creating a dummy string

Comment: @Bruno  Am getting some error as follows - error: no viable conversion from 'std::__ndk1::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to 'const char *'
          env->SetObjectArrayElement(fresult,i,env->NewStringUTF(finalResult[i]))

Comment: use the `c_str()` method of `std::string`. Also make sure that your string is actually UTF-8 or ASCII.

Comment: My bad, I wrote my example to quickly. As @Botje said, use the `c_str()` method. I've edited my answer

Comment: My JNI not returning any result though i can run successfully. @Botje How do i convert string array to UTF- 8?

Comment: strange...what is the signature or your Java method ? I'm doing this in Kotlin : `external fun arrayFromCplus(): Array<String>`

Comment: public static native String [] AnalyseSevenSegmentDisplay(long inputMat);

Comment: finalResult[i] creating array is right way ? or we need utf-8 or ascii conversion?

Comment: Got it @Bruno Thank you very much guys you made my day. n Save my day

Comment: Note: `NewStringUTF` uses the _modified_ UTF-8 encoding. It's unlikely that's what the native strings use. If passed UTF-8 that isn't identical to modified UTF-8, anything could happen. The `String(byte[] bytes, String charset)`constructor is a universal solution (and is much easier to use in Java than JNI). [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset))